# IPA server configuration: Cannot use IP network address

Tags: centos, ldap

I am stuck with an error while configuring IdM server for my environment. I got this weird error

```
invalid ip address 192.168.1.77 for server.example.com: cannot use ip network address
```

The error came soon after it asked for my domain name. The domain name is set at

```
/etc/resolv.conf and also at /etc/hosts file
```

Also the hostname of my server is set as

```
server.test.com
```

Please help me out of this. My ip address is not a public ip or a network address it is

```
192.168.1.77/32
```

Please tell me where I went wrong.

Bytor : I created two virtual machines (One as server and other as a client) just to test my scenario before I implemented it in my production. There aren't any other systems in this network.
Regards.

Vivek

Comment: Do you have another machine with that IP address already on the network?

Comment: No i dont have am sure.

Comment: Expand on your question saying where you are entering this in.

Comment: Bytor : I created two virtual machines. One as server and other as a client. Just to test my scenario before i implement it in my production. There isnt any other systems in this network.

Comment: What's the netmask/broadcast of your address? If you have set up the local address as 192.168.1.77/32 than the script will complain because addr = network. Show us the output of 'ip addr'.

Comment: My reply is not an answer any how it may help someone in future to setup an IDM server in RHEL 7 based servers. Kindly refer below URL
https://www.linuxsysadmins.com/step-by-step-installing-an-identity-management-server-in-linux-using-ipa/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Somebody from [this thread rom freeipa-users](https://www.redhat.com/archives/freeipa-users/2014-November/msg00119.html) is having the same problem. /32 is not a valid hostmask as far as the install script is concerned (no gateway / no routing). You can fix the netmask and this should work better.

I personally am encountering this issue on a google compute engine instance, which gets a dhcp address with a /32 netmask. I'm not sure why the google people do this, when they give you the whole /16 to work with.

Answer (score 0):

This was actually resolved a few months ago. It should be in version 4.4.3 or later.

https://fedorahosted.org/freeipa/ticket/5814

Answer (score -1):

The netmask is indeed the cause. I did the following sequence (note that the UPPERCASE letters need to be filled in with your values:

Do the following from the console if possible:

```
nmcli connection mod YOURCONNECTIONNAME ipv4.addresses 192.168.1.77/16
nmcli connection reload
systemctl restart network
ifdown YOURNIC; ifup YOURNIC
```

Comment: The question is for CentOS which doesn't use `nmcli`.  Also note that your answer is very badly formatted.

Comment: CentOS *does* have nmcli, at least the 7.x series.
I notice that on my cell phone, the formatting is indeed bad - sorry
about that.